# Apollo client useQuery not updating data after useMutation

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Using this mutation:

```
import produce from 'immer

const [createItem] = useMutation(CREATE_ITEM, {
update (client, { data: { createItem } }) {
  const queryResults = client.readQuery({
    query: GET_LATEST_ORDER,
    variables: { orderDepth: 1 }
  })

  client.writeQuery({
    query: GET_LATEST_ORDER,
    variables: { orderDepth: 1 },
    data: produce(queryResults, draft => {
      draft.orders[0].items.push(createItem)
    })
  })
}
```

})

I am unable to get

```
  const { loading, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_LATEST_ORDER, {
variables: { orderDepth: 1 }
```

})

to show updated data after the mutation.

The apollo cache is updated correctly.  But data on the useQuery does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being the returned object from the mutation was not exactly the same.  It was missing an @client field.
While obvious in hindsight no where I searched described this as a reason except for a comment I saw mentioning perhaps missing the __typename. 
This would have been obvious had apollo thrown an error.  However, no error was thrown, nor existed on the useQuery.